# What happens between SelectionChanged and SelectedCellsChanged in a WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a Datagrid with some rows in it and I want to select corresponding rows, when a user selects a row. When I do this in the SelectionChanged-Event, the rows get selected (dataGrid.SelectedItems is set correctly), but this is not displayed in the GUI (only the row header is selected - not the row).

If I select the additional rows in the SelectedCellsChanged-Event, everything works as expected. Does anybody know, what is happening in between? Or better: What should be the correct way to do this?

Here is some code to reproduce (BTW: using .Net 4.5.1):

```
    <DataGrid SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged" Name="myDatagrid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedCellsChanged="myDatagrid_SelectedCellsChanged"/>

    private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Does not display correctly
        // myDatagrid.SelectedItems.Add(somerow)
    }

    private void myDatagrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Does display correctly
        // myDatagrid.SelectedItems.Add(somerow)
    }
```

Comment: That should cause `StackOverflowException`. Don't change selection in selection change related events.

Comment: don't worry about that: Of course I use a flag to prevent a loop and therefore a `StackOverflowException`.